# AngularJS UTC Date filter

Tags: angularjs, date, utc, angularjs-filter

Is there a way in AngularJS to take a json date like this:

```
2014-01-29T21:45:24 +05:00
```

and output it as a date like this:

```
January 29, 2014
```

[Here's a JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/soruvine/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

There is [`date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) filter

```
{{ date_expression | date : 'MMMM  dd, YYYY'}}
```